# How to pass a variable from a while loop into a function then echo back to the while loop. PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, while-loop

```
    <?php
$tubeid = array('vYoutubeid' => "z2RhMdOJKio",
               'vYoutubeid2' => "Ty1Znqb-3z8",
               'vYoutubeid3'  => "AbRO0wJJhww",
                'vYoutubeid4'  => "AbRO0wJJhww");

function youtube_video_duration($description) 
  {
  $video_id = $description;
 $data = @file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'
  . $video_id . '?v=2&alt=jsonc');
  if ($data == FALSE) 
      return FALSE;


  $obj = json_decode($data);
  $dur= $obj->data->duration;
  return $dur;
   }

while (list($item, $description) = each($tubeid))
    echo "$item: $description<br>";
    echo youtube_video_duration($description);
```

here's what I'm trying to do.

Take the results from the array, While loop them show their value then take those values and run them through the function so i can return durations from youtube.

I'm stuck.

Comment: You're missing the block for while.

Comment: can you give an example of exactly what you want to do ?

Comment: for each description vYoutubeId I would like to return a duration.

Comment: Like @AshwinMukhija said, you need a curly braces for your while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the block for while. –  Ashwin Mukhija Dec 30 '13 at 19:45

that fixed it.